# Serialize Object into Form Data

Tags: extjs

I am trying to submit a request with form data like this:

```
playdate: 2017-08-06
players[1][name]: Alex
players[1][username]: Alex
players[1][score]: 51
```

However, if I add a players object like this:

```
var players = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().map(function(record) {
    return record.getData();
});
form.submit({
    url:'log.php' 
    params: {
        players: players
    }
});
```

then ExtJS submits it like this:

```
playdate: 2017-08-06
players: [object Object]
```

Doesn't ExtJS support serializing an object for a form-urlencoded request?

[Relevant fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24vn)

Comment: Why dont you send stringify data to server.For example Ext.encode() or Ext.JSON.encode(). Check it it solves your issue.

Comment: I cannot change the backend, the boardgamegeek server cannot take stringified input.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-submit).
It should work using the property `jsonSubmit:true` in your submit-call:

```
form.submit({
    url:'log.php' 
    params: {
        players: players
    },
    jsonSubmit: true
});
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It does not do a form submit when using jsonSubmit. Of course it doesn't, because I would have told ExtJS to do a json submit, which is not intended.